# Count followed values in a column Python

Tags: python, pandas

I need to count repated values and declare a condition when this repated values occurs 3 time followed.
This is my data set:

`Deviation Condition
0   1.875   Normal
2   0.625   Normal
3   0.000   Normal
4   1.250   Normal
5   1.875   Normal
6   0.000   Normal
7   10.000  Abnormal
8   20.000  Abnormal
9   30.000  Abnormal
10  40.000  Abnormal
11  50.000  Abnormal
12  60.000  Abnormal
13  70.000  Abnormal
14  80.000  Abnormal
15  90.000  Abnormal`

If Abnormal appears 3 times followed I want to declare failure

Comment: It would help if you post what you have tried so far in the question ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) to count the amount of consecutive `Abnormal`, and map the result to the values of interest:

```
df['state'] = (df.Condition.eq('Abnormal')
                 .rolling(window=3, center=False).apply(all)
                 .map({0:'Success', 1:'Failure'})
                 .fillna('Success'))
```

---

```
print(df)

     Deviation Condition  state
0       1.875    Normal  Success
2       0.625    Normal  Success
3       0.000    Normal  Success
4       1.250    Normal  Success
5       1.875    Normal  Success
6       0.000    Normal  Success
7      10.000  Abnormal  Success
8      20.000  Abnormal  Success
9      30.000  Abnormal  Failure
10     40.000  Abnormal  Failure
11     50.000  Abnormal  Failure
12     60.000  Abnormal  Failure
13     70.000  Abnormal  Failure
14     80.000  Abnormal  Failure
15     90.000  Abnormal  Failure
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) + [`Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html)

```
n = 3
df['state'] = (df['Condition'].where(df['Condition'].eq('Normal'))
                              .ffill(limit = n-1)
                          .replace('Normal','Success')
                          .fillna('Failure'))
print(df)
    Deviation Condition    state
0       1.875    Normal  Success
2       0.625    Normal  Success
3       0.000    Normal  Success
4       1.250    Normal  Success
5       1.875    Normal  Success
6       0.000    Normal  Success
7      10.000  Abnormal  Success
8      20.000  Abnormal  Success
9      30.000  Abnormal  Failure
10     40.000  Abnormal  Failure
11     50.000  Abnormal  Failure
12     60.000  Abnormal  Failure
13     70.000  Abnormal  Failure
14     80.000  Abnormal  Failure
15     90.000  Abnormal  Failure
```

or

```
n = 3
m = (df['Condition'].eq('Abnormal')
                    .groupby(df['Condition'].ne(df['Condition'].shift()).cumsum())
                    .cumsum()
                    .gt(n-1))
df['state'] = np.where(m,'Failure','Success')
```